# Adding a link to a website on my app error on

Tags: android, hyperlink

Trying to add a link to twitter.com on my app. The app runs but "unfortunately closes" when I click the follow us link.

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette/com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.Twitter};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3404)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3354)
>               at com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.WingmanListActivity.twitter(WingmanListActivity.java:89)
>               at com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.WingmanListActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(WingmanListActivity.java:77)
>               at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2570)

I can see where the error is but I do not know how to fix it. Please help.

This is the code where the error is pointing to

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_refresh: {
                updateTipList();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.action_favorites: {
                showFavorites();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.action_new: {
                newTip();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.twitter: {
                twitter();
                break;
                }
            }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void twitter() {
        Intent a = new Intent(this, Twitter.class);
        startActivityForResult(a, 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette/com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.Twitter}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You should declare your Twitter class on your AndroidManifest.xml file. Like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.Twitter"></activity>
```